# How to enable and disable button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

We are using MVC popup model where having two text box SSN number and DOB(Date of birth), i am using datepicker calendar for DOB and it is read only text box, for SSN number i am manually put the number in text box. i have written the below code to enable next button when SSN number and DOB both are correct. But below code is not working properly, First i put the SSN number and When i Select the DOB using calendar, next button is not enable, Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
$("#SocialSecurityNumber").blur(function () {

        if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
            $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        else {

            $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

        }

    });

    $("#SocialSecurityNumber").keyup(function () {
        if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
            $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        else {

            $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

        }

    });


    $("#DateofBirth").blur(function () {

        if ($("#DateofBirth").val() !='' && $("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11) {
            $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
        }
        else {

            $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

        }

    });

    $("#DateofBirth").keyup(function () {
        if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
            $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
        }

        else {

            $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

        }
    });
```

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: please comment this. so we can find out what do you want to do in these statements

Comment: can you please share your HTML? and as for what code you have written i think these are the scenarios:
1. if user only enter the `SSN` next button will not be enabled as the `DOB` field is empty.
2.If the user had entered `SSN` and enter the `DOB`(not select the date by any plugin as `keyup` and `blur` will not work but `onChange` might) then the next button will be enabled.

Comment: Please find below my HTML.

Comment: Please find below my HTML. Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateofBirth, new { class = "DateofBirth form-control txtWithImage", placeholder = "_ / / _ _ _", readonly = "readonly" })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jquery this is how you should disable a button

`$('#id_of_the_button').prop('disabled', true);`

to enable the button

`$('#pc_add').prop('disabled', false);`

in your html the button should be like this

```
<button id="id_of_the_button"> text of the button </button>
```

To answer your question here how you should implement your html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#SocialSecurityNumber").keyup(function() {
     if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
        $("#nextSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $("#nextSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });

    $('#DateofBirth').change(function() {
         if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
         $("#nextSubmit").prop('disabled', false);
        }else {
            $("#nextSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="SocialSecurityNumber" />
    <input type="date" id="DateofBirth" />
    <button id="nextSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please find below my HTML.                                                      
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateofBirth, new { class = "DateofBirth form-control txtWithImage", placeholder = "_ _/_ _/_ _ _ _", readonly = "readonly" })

Comment: i have tried the your code but no luck, When i click on DOB  text box second time then next button is enable.

Comment: please check again I have added  full script

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `blur and keyup` events, use the `change` event on input.

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="SocialSecurityNumber" />
    <input type="date" id="DateofBirth" />
    <button id="nextSubmit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    $("#SocialSecurityNumber").change(function() {
      if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
        $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
      } else {

        $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

      }

    });


    $("#DateofBirth").change(function() {

      if ($("#DateofBirth").val() != '' && $("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11) {
        $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
      } else {

        $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

      }

    });

    $("#DateofBirth").keyup(function() {
      if ($("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11 && $("#DateofBirth").val() != '') {
        $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");
      } else {

        $("#nextSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");

      }
    });
  </script>

  <body>
```

Comment: i have fixed this issue, in datepicker function i have call the onchange event which fixed the issue. thanks for your help.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi All, i have fixed this issue, in datepicker function i have write the on change event which fixed the issue. Please find below code, thanks for your help.                 
 .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
 if ($("#DateofBirth").val() == '' && $("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length == 11) {
                     var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#nextSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#nextSubmit").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!-- To disable button -->
$('#ElememtId').prop("disabled",true)
```

and

```
<!-- To enable button -->
$('#ElememtId').prop("disabled",false)
```